# Pulling docker image to Heroku container

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-ci

I am trying to deploy a Docker Image to Heroku. The image is external and hosted on https://quay.io/repository/mldb/mldb?tab=info.

- To run the image, I have created an app on Heroku. The app is called still-dawn-24875.
- I log into the heroku container.
- Now I am trying to pull the docker image from repository. I am running the following command -

*heroku container:pull --verbose --app=still-dawn-24875 mldb*

The command is throwing following error -

=== Pulling mldb as registry.heroku.com/still-dawn-24875/mldb

heroku-container-registry docker [ 'pull', 'registry.heroku.com/still-dawn-24875/mldb' ] +0ms

Using default tag: latest

> Error response from daemon: manifest for
>   registry.heroku.com/still-dawn-24875/mldb:latest not found: manifest
>   unknown: manifest unknown

!  1

I have tried this with another repository on Docker Hub as well. It gives me the same error.

Any idea on what could be the issue and how we can resolve this?